# The multi-part identifier "Task.end_date" could not be bound ----harish

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have this query:

```
SELECT  TM_User.FullName ,
                Task.end_date
        FROM    TM_User
        INNER JOIN ( 
            SELECT Task.task_id ,
                Task_Hours.user_id ,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY Task.end_date DESC ) rtt ,
                Task.end_date
            FROM   Task_Hours
            INNER JOIN ( 
                SELECT Task.task_id ,
                    Task.end_date ,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Task.task_id ORDER BY Task.end_date DESC ) rr
                FROM   Task
                WHERE  Task.start_dte >= '2013-08-15'
                    AND Task.end_date <= '2013-08-31'
             ) Task ON Task.task_id = Task_Hours.task_id
        ) a ON TM_User.TM_UserID = a.user_id
        WHERE   a.rtt = 1
                AND is_active = 1
```

Comment: but i am getting error in this query that ie The multi-part identifier "Task.end_date" could not be bound.
why it is coming can any body tell me

Comment: You shouldn't ever need to directly comment to your own question. If you have more information to add, you can click the edit link at the bottom to include it. This can also help because you can include an error message and mark it up as a quote (fourth button from left) which helps it to stand out - there's a lot less formatting available in the comments area.

Answer (score 1):

By the time you're writing the outermost `SELECT` clause, only two rowset names/aliases are still in scope, `TM_User` (a table or view) and `a` (the name you've given to a subquery).

So use the name for the rowset that contains `end_date` - `a`:

```
SELECT  TM_User.FullName ,
                a.end_date
        FROM    TM_User
        INNER JOIN ( 
            SELECT Task.task_id ,
                Task_Hours.user_id ,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY Task.end_date DESC ) rtt ,
                Task.end_date
            FROM   Task_Hours
            INNER JOIN ( 
                SELECT Task.task_id ,
                    Task.end_date ,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Task.task_id ORDER BY Task.end_date DESC ) rr
                FROM   Task
                WHERE  Task.start_dte >= '20130815'
                    AND Task.end_date <= '20130831'
             ) Task ON Task.task_id = Task_Hours.task_id
        ) a ON TM_User.TM_UserID = a.user_id
        WHERE   a.rtt = 1
                AND is_active = 1
```

(Also changed the date literals to be unambiguous)

Comment: Thank 

Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: Thank u Damien_The_Unbeliever